# How can I display summarization progress percentage when using hugging face transformers

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am running the below code but I have 0 idea how much time is remaining. It can be hours, days, etc.

I really would like to see some sort of progress during the summarization.

Any help is appreciated

By the way It is taking really long time on RTX 3060 - 12GB vram even with as small as 9k token input

```
wall_of_text="some long text..."
import torch
from transformers import pipeline

summarizer = pipeline(
    "summarization",
    "pszemraj/long-t5-tglobal-base-16384-book-summary",
    device=0 if torch.cuda.is_available() else -1,
)

result = summarizer(wall_of_text,min_length=500,max_length=16384,no_repeat_ngram_size=3, 
           encoder_no_repeat_ngram_size =3,
           repetition_penalty=3.5,
           num_beams=4,
           early_stopping=True)
with open('pszemraj-long-t5-tglobal-base-16384-book-summary.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result[0]['summary_text'])
```

Comment: Is it taking super long just for one piece of text? How long is your wall of text? I know how to make it display a progress bar for a list of texts to be summarized, but not sure that's what you're looking for

Comment: @Saint it is over 10k tokens. It can be even more up to 50k tokens as well. So how can I see how much estimated time to complete in 1 batch like with 10k tokens? By list of text i presume you split it into smaller pieces and display completed piece count?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the progress for a single long string of text.

However, if you split your large text into a list of smaller ones, then according to [this answer](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/14789#issuecomment-998639662), you can convert the list to pytorch Dataset and then use it with `tqdm`:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from tqdm import tqdm 
# from tqdm.notebook import tqdm  # Uncomment for Jupyter Environment


# Split your text into a list of smaller ones
# list_of_texts = []
# ...


class ListDataset(Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, original_list):
        self.original_list = original_list

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.original_list)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.original_list[i]


dataset = ListDataset(list_of_texts)

summarizer_kwargs = dict(
    min_length=500,
    max_length=16384,
    no_repeat_ngram_size=3, 
    encoder_no_repeat_ngram_size =3,
    repetition_penalty=3.5,
    num_beams=4,
    early_stopping=True
)

result = [i for i in tqdm(summarizer(dataset, **summarizer_kwargs))]
```